# jqGrid search filter questions

Tags: search, jqgrid

Have two questions.

1. Make the search filter form non modal.
2. Allow searching by pressing enter key instead of having to press the Find button. 
   thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking to make search filter non modal, to have a an api that you can execute and filter data

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? non modal search window? The integrated search is less then ideal! The edit form seems ok as you can do edittype:"checkbox",editoptions:{value:"Yes:No",defaultValue:"Yes"}  but there does not seem to be the same support for searching.

Maybe some way you can hiJack their post/gets and add your own paramaters?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to me - perhaps you should be asking this of the jqgrid programmers?

Answer (score 3):

sachin,

Your question seems to be more of a statement, but if you're looking for various options for jqgrid, take a look at:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#

> New in Version 3.5 > Integrated Search Toolbar

This allows you to interactively search and it respects the Enter key.

However, you lose operators... but I suppose you could modify the code that's given to add something similar back in (or bundle your operator in with the text....ie, user enters "> 400" rather than "400", but this poses security risks)